# Restore From Database not showing database I want to pick

Tags: sql-server-2008, backup-restoration

In Management Studio I want to restore to a point in time from an existing database.  However, the databases that I can choose from in the drop down list don't include the one I want to choose.  And oddly, there are databases in the list that have been deleted too.

I closed/re-opened Management Studio in hopes it would refresh but no such luck.

Anyone know what the deal is here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if you restored a database using a full database backup, but specified a new name for the new database, the drop down menu in the Restore Database dialog in SSMS will show the name from the original backup, not the new name you specified

Another situation when a database is not shown in the drop down menu in the Restore Database dialog is when no database backups have been made for the database

Comment: Ok, so let's say I took a backup of a database and restored it to a different computer and named it differently.  Then if I wanted to restore to a point in time from there, I wouldn't be able to do it using SMSS because the drop down would show the original name but I imagine I could still do it from a script.  Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes, you can use the syntax given here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179451(v=sql.105).aspx  Please note that the database name in the RESTORE DATABASE is the new database name (not the original one)

Comment: "Another situation when a database is not shown in the drop down menu in the Restore Database dialog is when no database backups have been made for the database" - thank you so much!